# GCP panes do not show any project items in Firefox normal mode, the items only show up in Firefox incognito mode or Google Chrome normal mode

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firefox

I am not sure whether this fits to Server Fault Stack Exchange, and it has already been closed on [Super User Stack Exchange](https://superuser.com/questions/1744774/google-cloud-platform-gcp-panes-all-blank-in-firefox-normal-mode-but-working). It is a problem of Firefox, not of GCP.

GCP panes do not show any filled items in any of the GCP projects in Firefox normal mode, while all of the items are shown in Firefox incognito mode and in Google Chrome normal mode. How to get the GCP items back in Firefox normal mode?

## Examples

For example, checking the Google Cloud Platform (GCP) Logging is just empty:

[image]

Or the GCP Cloud Functions, just 0:

[image]

while I can see everything when entering Firefox in incognito mode where I have to login with email and password.

## Tried

Tried in normal mode:

- signed out and in again
- checked it in a new tab
- checked it in a new window
- checked everything after a machine restart

### Removing the Google cookies did not work either

I also removed the cookies of [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) and signed in again:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Yet, I still do not see any items, though I can see them with the same login in private browsing.

Comment: This is still ongoing after a month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling any extensions (*Settings* --> *Extensions and Themes* or just browse: *about:addons*) you have in Firefox and then reloading the page. In my case it was a vim navigation extension that was interfering.

Comment: Worked for me, disabling the "Dark Mode" extension.